# All built-in .Net attributes

Tags: c#, linq

I have used `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` to list all assemblies, but how do I list all built-in attributes in .NET 2.0 using C#?

Answer (score 16):

Note that `AppDomain.GetAssemblies()` will only list the *loaded* assemblies... but then it's easy:

```
var attributes = from assembly in assemblies
                 from type in assembly.GetTypes()
                 where typeof(Attribute).IsAssignableFrom(type)
                 select type;
```

.NET 2.0 (non-LINQ) version:

```
List<Type> attributes = new List<Type>();
foreach (Assembly assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
{
    foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
    {
        if (typeof(Attribute).IsAssignableFrom(type))
        {
            attributes.Add(type);
        }
    }                   
}
```

Comment: I'd give +2 for mentioning that it only lists loaded assemblies if I could!

Comment: added 2.0 version. @arco: you really start to appreciate linq when you have to go back to the old way.